# Method of keeping a Java program running indefinitely that is efficient?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

My program starts in main, and fire off a few threads that do the work of the program (reading sensors, updating a database, displaying information to a screen). I want the program to run indefinitely.

At the moment after my threads have started in main I just have:

```
public static void main(String []args)
{
    //threads start here
    while(true) {}
}
```

Obviously this works but I am wondering if it is wasting resources looping.

Is there an efficient way to keep the program running. Is there a graceful way to exit?
i.e. start an event listener in main that listens for a keyboard or event or something?

I also tried this if it is any better:

```
while(true) {
    TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(1);
}
```

EDIT: more info regarding the threads:

I'm not sure what type of thread they are. I am implementing an interface called gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener, that starts and handles the threads, so its abstracted away from me. I'll have to have a look at the API, although I think it isn't well documented, or look at the source I guess. They keep the JVM alive in the IDE (blueJ) but not when I run the program on the command line.
I just use the interface's method to add an event listener to a com port which starts the threads running.

Comment: You should also add some code that shows how you are starting the threads. I assume you're setting the daemon flag.

Comment: Ok thanks will do now

Comment: No program runs forever. There should usually always be a way to stop and restart it. At least when the system shuts down, a program should be able to stop and cleanup orderly.

Comment: I agree I need to look into how to do that. I'm new to Java and multi-threading. I usually program in C where I can do all that stuff easily. A bit confused how to do it in java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless your threads are `daemon threads` I don't see why you should have a while or for that matter any loops which would just eat your CPU. Your main thread will not be killed unless all non daemon threads are completed. Also if you wish to do cleanup you can register a JVM's shutdown hook.

Comment: Yeah when I run the program in the terminal it just starts and then closes. If I put while(true) {} in main it works fine. Im writing out to the terminal, so I dont want it to close.

Comment: @c_breeez: Aniket is correct, 1+. The concern is that either the threads you've launched are ending for some reason (why?), or they are daemon threads that don't keep the JVM running (why would they be daemon threads?). You need to figure out the whys.

Comment: If you are not explicitly setting `setDaemon(true)` then the behavior is inherited from the parent thread - main thread in your case which is by default non-daemon in nature.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels mmmm. I'm not sure what type of thread they are. I am implementing an interface called gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener, that starts and handles the threads, so its abstracted away from me. I'll have to have a look at the API, although I think it isn't well documented, or look at the source I guess. They keep the JVM alive in the IDE (blueJ) but not when I run the program on the command line.

Comment: The wording of the answer is a bit misleading. When the main method ends, the main thread *will* terminate, regardless of how many other threads are there. But the JVM will not terminate if there’s at least one non-daemon thread running.

Answer (score 2):

I do something similar with my RMI servers. Instead of an endless while loop you can use an endless wait().

```
private final Object forever = new Object();
synchronized (forever) {
  try { forever.wait() } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
}
```

The other problem is how do you end this server? When I want to end it I start a new thread that issues a System.exit(0); that kills the JVM. Obviously you would need to program a way to get to this code.

Comment: in java does system.exit(0); tidy everything up, like close threads and say db connections before exiting. Im used to C where you do everything manually so Im unsure what the JVM does for you and what you need to do yourself.

Comment: Not so. You need to do all that yourself just like C. You can have a listener waiting for a button push. When pushed, clean up and System.exit(0); The reason I start a shut_down thread is because I send a message back to the calling RMI Client and if using an immediate exit(0) that message would never be sent. The shut_down thread sleeps for 2 seconds before calling exit().

Comment: Cool I think I will make a shutdown sequences that tidies everything up and exits. And maybe just listen for a keypress event or something to shutdown

Comment: You can do the same much simpler: `for(;;) LockSupport.park();`, doesn’t need a dummy object and is shorter while already containing the code for guarding against spurious wakeups.